# How to transfer server level login permissions to a higher sql version?

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL 2017 with several server level logins/roles/permissions, linked servers, agent jobs.

While I can easily script agent jobs and linked servers, and backup/restore the user dbs to transfer the database level users/roles/permissions, I'm finding it challenging to move the server level login/roles/permissions.

I have looked into the sp rev login script from Microsoft but it only shows me the logins and roles. It doesn't give me the granular permissions.

Also I can't restore system dbs from SQL 2017 to SQL 2019. So is there any other simple way to transfer server level login/roles/permissions?

Comment: Why can't you restore the database?

Comment: If you mean master db, then it is because version is different.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misred it!

Answer (score 1):

please try these scripts:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON  
-- Scripting Out the Logins To Be Created  
SELECT 'IF (SUSER_ID('+QUOTENAME(SP.name,'''')+') IS NULL) BEGIN CREATE LOGIN ' +QUOTENAME(SP.name)+  
CASE   
WHEN SP.type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN' THEN ' WITH PASSWORD = ' +CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),SL.password_hash,1)+ ' HASHED, CHECK_EXPIRATION = '   
+ CASE WHEN SL.is_expiration_checked = 1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END +', CHECK_POLICY = ' +CASE WHEN SL.is_policy_checked = 1 THEN 'ON,' ELSE 'OFF,' END  
ELSE ' FROM WINDOWS WITH'  
END   
+' DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' +SP.default_database_name+ '], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[' +SP.default_language_name+ '] END;' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [-- Logins To Be Created --]  
FROM sys.server_principals AS SP LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins AS SL  
ON SP.principal_id = SL.principal_id  
WHERE SP.type IN ('S','G','U')  
AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'  
AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'  
AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'  
AND SP.name <> ('sa');  

-- Scripting Out the Role Membership to Be Added  
SELECT   
'EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N''' + SL.name + ''', @rolename = N''' + SR.name + '''  
' AS [-- Server Roles the Logins Need to be Added --]  
FROM master.sys.server_role_members SRM  
JOIN master.sys.server_principals SR ON SR.principal_id = SRM.role_principal_id  
JOIN master.sys.server_principals SL ON SL.principal_id = SRM.member_principal_id  
WHERE SL.type IN ('S','G','U')  
AND SL.name NOT LIKE '##%##'  
AND SL.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'  
AND SL.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'  
AND SL.name <> ('sa');  


-- Scripting out the Permissions to Be Granted  
SELECT   
CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'   
THEN SrvPerm.state_desc   
ELSE 'GRANT'   
END  
+ ' ' + SrvPerm.permission_name + ' TO [' + SP.name + ']' +   
CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'   
THEN ''   
ELSE ' WITH GRANT OPTION'   
END collate database_default AS [-- Server Level Permissions to Be Granted --]   
FROM sys.server_permissions AS SrvPerm   
JOIN sys.server_principals AS SP ON SrvPerm.grantee_principal_id = SP.principal_id   
WHERE   SP.type IN ( 'S', 'U', 'G' )   
AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'  
AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'  
AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'  
AND SP.name <> ('sa');  

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```